# Background images not appearing in cards anymore

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

My app was functioning fine until sometime last week.  For some reason all the background images stopped appearing in the actual Google Glass.  They do appear in the playgorund.  Anyone know how to fix this?  Here's an example of my app home card (I changed the URLs).  The home.jpg image does not appear.

```
    {
  "kind": "mirror#timelineItem",
  "id": "a48a9a6a-67df-4035-859f-b33f05c4e11e",
  "created": "2013-06-14T16:24:17.460Z",
  "updated": "2013-06-14T16:24:17.460Z",
  "etag": "\"r3ghbVW9Rp1kDP4UexS05_pFx4E/gCTDXyXBhsaPhUc6MnVaYblah\"",
  "html": "<article class=\"photo\">\t<img src=\"https://myapp.appspot.com/static/images/home.jpg?cacheKiller=098234092384\" width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\">\t<div class=\"photo-overlay\"></div>\t<section>\t\t<p class=\"text-auto-size\"></p>\t</section></article>",
  "menuItems": [
    {
      "id": "menu1",
      "action": "CUSTOM",
      "values": [
        {
          "displayName": "Menu 1",
          "iconUrl": "https://myapp.appspot.com/static/images/icon.png?cacheKiller=098234092384"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "menu2",
      "action": "CUSTOM",
      "values": [
        {
          "displayName": "Menu 2",
          "iconUrl": "https://myapp.appspot.com/static/images/icon.png?cacheKiller=098234092384"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "menu3",
      "action": "CUSTOM",
      "values": [
        {
          "displayName": "Menu 3",
          "iconUrl": "https://myapp.appspot.com/static/images/icon.png?cacheKiller=098234092384"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "menu4",
      "action": "CUSTOM",
      "values": [
        {
          "displayName": "Menu 4",
          "iconUrl": "https://myapp.appspot.com/static/images/icon.png?cacheKiller=098234092384"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "pinned",
      "action": "TOGGLE_PINNED"
    }
  ],
  "notification": {
    "level": "DEFAULT"
  }
}
```

Comment: There was an issue that got introduced by a bad CSS style that should have been fixed by now. Can you confirm that you are still experiencing this?

Comment: Confirmed, I'm still seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a more widespread problem, possibly since the introduction of XE6. In many of the cases, the background image will show up later.

Since you have some concrete examples of this, I suggest you open a bug in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).

Comment: done, thanks.  https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=112&thanks=112&ts=1371490107

Answer (score 0):

An update was made and issue corrected. Just need to soft reset (hold down for 15 seconds) and be connected to data.

The issue was css related for photos.  It did not effect videos.